# How to list the train operators that use the second oldest trains (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql

train_operators:

```
| train_operator_id |  name  |  
------------------------------
| 1                 | Virgin |
| 2                 |  First |
```

journeys:

```
| journey_id | train_operator | train_type |
--------------------------------------------
| 1          | 2              | 2          |
| 2          | 2              | 1          |
| 3          | 1              | 3          |
| 4          | 1              | 2          |
```

train_types:

```
| train_type_id | date_made  |
------------------------------
| 1             | 1999-02-15 |
| 2             | 2001-03-11 |
| 3             | 2000-12-05 |
```

How would you write a query to find all the train operators that use the second oldest type of train?

With the given schema the query should result with just Virgin since it is the only train operator that uses the second oldest train type

Comment: Nitpick: Name train_type and train_type_id the same.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select distinct train_operator from journeys 
    inner join (Select * from train_types order by date_made LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1) sectrain 
    on sectrain.train_type_id = journeys.train_type
```

You're into the UK Rail Network are you? I used to work for Funkwerk IT, who in turn used to provide the timetable planning software for Network Rail...

Comment: I'm getting into it, at least I'm getting into databases about trains. It's just a project I decided to do to learn PSQL. Did you use it a lot with Funkwerk (awesome name for a company)?

Comment: Thanks for all your answers, they seem to do the trick and all in different ways too which is interesting. Out of further interest, although it's a bit of a vague question, what is your thought process when coming up with queries?

Comment: I start with the From Clause, and look at how I can get to the information I want. Selecting fields comes later... Foreign keys in the tables can be a big clue...

Answer (score 2):

It can be pretty easy using the power of window functions in pg

```
SELECT DISTINCT train_operator_id, 
                name 
FROM   (SELECT t.train_operator_id, 
               t.name, 
               Rank() OVER (ORDER BY tt.date_made) AS rank 
        FROM   train_operators AS t 
               JOIN journeys AS j 
                 ON j.train_operator = t.train_operator_id 
               JOIN train_types AS tt 
                 ON tt.train_type_id = j.train_type) AS q 
WHERE  rank = 2;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/98816/8

Comment: Thanks for all your answers, they seem to do the trick and all in different ways too which is interesting. Out of further interest, although it's a bit of a vague question, what is your thought process when coming up with queries?

Comment: @HalfFrench SQL allows for unlimited number of ways to do the same thing. I must admit that mine query is probably gonna be a bit slower than the other two but it allows to pick second, fourth and 11th oldest train easily and will work if two trains have the same date_made. As for the thought process I'm afraid I don't have enough experience to advise on that.

Answer (score 1):

```
select to.name
from
    train_operators to
    inner join
    journeys j on to.train_operator_id = j.train_operator
where
    j.train_type = (
        select train_type_id
        from train_types
        order by date_made
        limit 1 offset 1
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for all your answers, they seem to do the trick and all in different ways too which is interesting. Out of further interest, although it's a bit of a vague question, what is your thought process when coming up with queries?

Comment: @Half I always start with the `from` clause.